# How to store 3D data in parallel always at the same coordinates?

Tags: c++, c, hdf5

I am trying to store 3D data (memory layout is a single array; data dimensions are `NX * NY * NZ`) to a HDF5 file. As I want to distribute the large array to multiple MPI processes, each process has a single data array with size `myNX * NY * NZ` where `myNX = NX / mpi_size`.

I want it to always write the same data to the same "coordinates" inside the HDF5 file so the number of processes writing/reading the HDF5 file does not have any influence on the data layout. Here's some of my code:

Setting up the local arrays:

```
data = new double[myNX * NY * NZ];
for(unsigned int k = 0; k < NZ; k++) {
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < NY; j++) {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < myNX; i++) {
            data[k * (myNX * NY) + j * myNX + i] = getValue(i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

`getValue()` returns a `double` like `i.j0k` so I can see where each entry ends up in the file (e.g. `i = 3`, `j = 2`, `k = 1` will result in `3.201`). For testing, I have put `NX = 9`; `NY = NZ = 2`.

File hyperslab:

```
hid_t h5_hyperslab_file_id = H5Dget_space(h5_dataset_id);
hsize_t offset[] = {0, 0, 0};
offset[0] = getOffsetX(mpi_rank, mpi_size);
hsize_t length[] = {myNX, NY, NZ};
hsize_t stride[] = {1, 1, 1};
H5Sselect_hyperslab(h5_hyperslab_file_id, H5S_SELECT_SET, offset, stride, length, NULL);
```

Memory hyperslab and file writing:

```
hid_t h5_memory_dataspace_id = H5Screate_simple(3, length, length);
h5_plist_id = H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_XFER);
H5Pset_dxpl_mpio(h5_plist_id, H5FD_MPIO_COLLECTIVE);
H5Dwrite(h5_dataset_id, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, h5_memory_dataspace_id, h5_hyperslab_file_id, h5_plist_id, data);
```

I messed around with various settings for memory and file hyper slab, but couldn't figure out the right one. Also the documentation on this is a bit vague (or at least I don't understand it properly :().

Thank you in advance,
Velines

Edit: For clarification: My problem is that my data is saved at different locations depending on the number of processing writing the file. So I need a way to create a "mapping" between my data array and the HDF5 file. How can I do that?